# Ruby Event machine stop vs stop_event_loop

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I am confused and can't find more info

What is the difference between EM.stop and EM.stop_event_loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the event loop, use EventMachine.stop_event_loop (aliased as EventMachine.stop)